# Creating a byte from an integer

Tags: java, int, byte

I want to create a byte using an integer. For example I have an integer of 4, I want to create a byte with a value of 4. When I do something like

```
byte test = 134;
```

I get an byte value of -122 wheras I want a byte value of simply 134 so that i can convert this to ascii later on.

I am unsure of how to achieve this but would welcome any help that can be provided. Thanks.

Comment: Bytes are always between -128 and 127.

Comment: _"I want a byte value of simply 134"_ The range for a byte value is `[-128, 127]`

Comment: That definitely does not compile.

Comment: What do you want to do for `562`?

Comment: There is no code point 134 in ASCII. The maximum ASCII value is 127 (DEL). This is, for some reason you will understand later, exactly the maximum byte value.

Comment: You're not talking about ASCII values in *octal* notation, are you? Octal 0134 is 0x5C, `'\'`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it went from -128 and 127. I thought it was just pure 0-255 (I am a networker so I do IP calculations) What i really need to do is say 23 + 32 in bytes and then create a new byte from the result? any ideas how this kind of example can be achieved?

Comment: @ChristopherBuckley If you are interested in learning more about byte and why it is between -128 and 127 see: http://blog-tothought.rhcloud.com/post/23

Answer (score 3):

In Java `byte`s are interpreted as signed (along with `int`s, `short`s, and `long`s). The unsigned byte value of `134` is bit-equivalent to the signed byte value of `-122`. If you wish to use the unsigned value of a `byte`, you can do so by storing this value in a signed integer with more than 8 bits, such as an `int`:

```
byte test = (byte) 134;
int unsignedByteValue = ((int) test) & 0xff;
// now unsignedByteValue == 134
```

The bitmask of `0xff` ensures that only the lower 8 bits of `unsignedByteValue` are ones. Otherwise, a negative signed `byte` would result in a negative signed `int` by sign extension.

Comment: can you explain what the second line does?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all bytes are signed. They have a value from -128 to 127. If you print out the byte, that's all you will get.

But Java has a different type for characters. You should use this instead:

```
char test = 134;
```

The `char` type is unsigned and will accommodate characters with numeric values up to 65,535.

Comment: You dont need to cast it.