# Converting 0xFF gives me -1 -> Signed vs Unsigned?

Tags: java, integer, hex, unsigned, signed

Here is my code:

```
byte b = (byte) 0xFF;
System.out.println(b);
```

I expect to see `255`, but instead I see `-1`. What's happening? Is the compiler using a signed instead of an unsigned byte?

Comment: Java is always signed. No unsigned types in Java

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246786/creating-a-byte-from-an-integer/21246942#21246942

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are confused about the difference between storage and representation.

As the others told you, Java only uses signed integral types. As a byte is only 8 bit, this means you have a range from -128 to 127. But keep in mind: This is only a decimal representation that does not tell you about the binary storage!

A better reminder for the range of Java's byte type would be the following (decimal) representation:

```
0 1 ... 126 127 -128 -127 ... -2 -1
```

This directly corresponds to the following binary representation:

```
00000000 00000001 ... 11111110 11111111
```

The signed decimal representation is called the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). As you can see, the binary value 11111111, which is exactly 0xFF, corresponds to the (signed) decimal value -1.

If you now send this value via a stream, you will get the full 0xFF value, regardless what you see in a Java program's console output.

Comment: Ok, one more thing : When I do "outputStream.write(CMD1)" and CMD1 is a byte = 0xFF, what goes on the port serial the 255 or the -1 ? Because is maybe just java compiler who doesn't translate on the console like I want but when I send on the port com it sends me the 255 :/ ?

Comment: Phhh ... The "-1" and the "255" are only representations for the binary 11111111. So, I recommend to not think in terms of "-1" or "255" (although thinking of 255 makes it easy, I guess). That said, you will soon realize that this "-1" or the "255" are not sent, but it is a bit stream consisting of 8 set bits (1's).

Comment: Yes, exactly. I got my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474001/outputstream-write-for-int-array

Answer (score 1):

In Java type `byte` is signed, it is not possible to use an "unsigned byte" in java. A workaround would be to use `short` types

Comment: Ok nice to know that but then how can I send a "255" in my cmd[0] variable ?

Comment: You can't. Now you say you are "sending" this array as a "command", you can either "convert" signed to unsigned in the receptor part (by doing `int z = (0xFF & byte[x])`) or send and receive a `short[]` or `int[]` instead of a `byte[]`

Comment: What does the x of byte[x] means ?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you operate on a byte variable in Java, `(byte) 0xFF` is going to be implicitly converted to `(int) 0xFFFFFF` (i.e. `-1`). You can do `0xFFFFFF & 0xFF` and then you'll get `(int) 255` as you wish (you will never be able to get `(byte) 255`, only `(int) 255`).

If you only need to store bytes, it doesn't matter how 0xFF is printed on the screen, it's still (byte) 0xFF internally. If you need to operate on them (comparing to an int, adding, subtracting, converting to a string, printing on the screen, and basically anything else), then you need to be aware that they'll get converted to int 0xFFFFFF which is interpreted -1.