# outputStream.write() for int[] array

Tags: java, arrays, int, byte, outputstream

I'm looking for something that does the same thing than `outputStream.write()` but which will accept an array of int.

Actually, I'm using this one : `outputStream.write()` but this one accepts only `byte`,`byte[]` or `int`.

I could use the `byte[]` but the values I want to send are

```
 [255,44,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255]
```

so I can use the `byte[]` because there range are only from  `-127 to 127` :/

It's to send a command on a Port_Com which accept only packet of 19 bytes and must be start and end with 255.

Comment: If all your values are in the range 0-255 inclusive, you should just use a `byte[]` instead. Cast each `int` to `byte` and you'll still get the right bits on the wire.

Comment: You sure, when I use byte[] and I put the value of 0xFF in byte[0] it shows me -1 instead of 255 :/ ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's the same bits, just interpreted in a different way.

Comment: @D3fman yes, but the 0s and 1s are the same, 255 is 1111 1111, which is -1 in signed parlance, I agree though this is one of the many things that makes me despise Java. unsigned int ftw!

Comment: Ok so when I put byte[0] = 0xFF and then I do outputStream.write(byte[0]) it sends 255 on my Port_Com ? Even if when I do sysout of byte[0] its show me -1 ?

Comment: As I said, I hate Java, you.... an int cast would cast that to minus 1..... @JonSkeet answer?

Comment: Ok but could you just answer my question up just by a yes or no ? Thanks

Comment: @AlecTeal just deal with it... Use masks if you want only the relevant bits

Comment: @D3fman it will not send 255 but it will send bits 1111 1111, and this is what you want

Comment: yes thats what I wanted to mean, thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: I don't think there's any need for another answer - Ingo's is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common misconception about bytes, because of rumors repeated again and again.

Actually, the range of byte is from

```
00000000 (binary) to   11111111 (binary)
```

There is no reason to interpret bytes as numbers, if you're only interested in the bit patterns. There is, in particular, no reason to interpret bytes as *signed* numbers, just because java does it that way by default.

Hence, go ahead, as Jon Skeet says, cast your integers to byte and write those bytes.